# IBM MQ 7 File Transfer

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm new to WebSphere MQ File Transfer, I want to send a file through Java code to Message Queue Server and read it from another end. Please let me know or any link where I can get the details to send a file through Message Queue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Previously i have achieved by writing the File content into the MQ and message id as File Name, but i think its not the right way, Please let me know or any Link where i can get the details to Send a File through MQ.

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to use WebSphere MQ File Transfer Edition from Java, or are you trying to move files through WebSphere MQ as messages using your Java code?

Answer (score 2):

WMQ File Transfer Edition is an advanced manage file transfer product. It comes with a MQ Explorer plug-in where you can configure your file transfers. It also has command line and script based interface for transfer configuration. This means that you don't need any coding to do file transfer. Just configuration is enough.

There is a redbook on [MQ FTE](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/sg247760.html). There are also some developerWorks articles. One that I like most is [WMQ FTE Walkthough](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1003_phillips/1003_phillips.html).